# Altair + panel: chart dynamic dropdown filter doesn't work

Tags: python, panel, altair

I almost have it, but the filter selection only works when executing the cell in jupyter. It doesn't get updated when the dropdown selector is used.
I have three parts:

1. A scatterplot that has to have a filter/dropdown menu bound to a list of values from a `df`'s column `Island`.
2. Altair brush of type `selection_interval` that is connected to the scatterplot.
3. When the scatterplot is rendered in (jupyter) and the brush selector is used, a table based on selected records form the `df` is rendered below the scatterplot and the records shown in the table are dynamically presented based on the brush selection.

It almost work perfectly, but the dropdown menu doesn't get updated for the scatterplot, BUT DOES get updated for the table. What am I missing here?
I need the dropdown to filter out the chart too. Below is the code and the animated gif

```
import panel as pn
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
pn.extension('vega', template='fast-list')

penguins_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vega/vega/master/docs/data/penguins.json"
df = pd.read_json(penguins_url)

brush = alt.selection_interval(name='brush')  # selection of type "interval"
island = pn.widgets.Select(name='Island', options=df.Island.unique().tolist())

chart = alt.Chart(df.query(f'Island == "{island.value}"')).mark_point().encode(
    x=alt.X('Beak Length (mm):Q', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    y=alt.Y('Beak Depth (mm):Q', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),  
    color=alt.condition(brush, 'Species:N', alt.value('lightgray'))
).properties(
    width=700,
    height=200
).add_selection(brush)

vega_pane = pn.pane.Vega(chart, debounce=5)

def filtered_table(selection, island):    
    if not selection:
        return '## No selection'
    query = ' & '.join(
        f'{crange[0]:.3f} <= `{col}` <= {crange[1]:.3f} & Island == "{island}"'
        for col, crange in selection.items()
    )
    return pn.Column(
        f'Query: {query}',
        pn.pane.DataFrame(df.query(query).query(f'Island == "{island}"'), width=600, height=300)
    )

pn.Column(
    pn.Row(island, vega_pane),
    pn.bind(filtered_table, selection = vega_pane.selection.param.brush, island=island))[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image: chart rendering and faulty filtering]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few examples of how to achieve this in https://github.com/holoviz/panel/issues/4487, e.g.:

```
def filter_table(data, selection):
    if not selection:
        return '## No selection'
    query = ' & '.join(
        f'{crange[0]:.3f} <= `{col}` <= {crange[1]:.3f}'
        for col, crange in selection.items()
    )
    return pn.Column(
        f'Query: {query}',
        pn.pane.DataFrame(data.query(query), width=600, height=300)
    )

penguins_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vega/vega/master/docs/data/penguins.json"
df = pd.read_json(penguins_url)

island_dropdown = pn.widgets.Select(options=df['Island'].unique().tolist(), width=300)

dynamic_data = pn.bind(lambda island: df.loc[df['Island'] == island], island_dropdown)

brush = alt.selection_interval(name='brush')  # selection of type "interval"
chart = alt.Chart(dynamic_data()).mark_point().encode(
    x=alt.X('Beak Length (mm):Q', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    y=alt.Y('Beak Depth (mm):Q', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),  
    color=alt.condition(brush, 'Species:N', alt.value('lightgray'))
).add_params(
    brush
)

altair_pane = pn.pane.Vega(chart)

def update_chart(_):
    altair_pane.object = chart.properties(data=dynamic_data())
    
island_dropdown.param.watch(update_chart, 'value')

pn.Column(
    island_dropdown,
    pn.Row(
        altair_pane,
        pn.bind(filter_table, dynamic_data, altair_pane.selection.param.brush)
    )
)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error
```AttributeError: 'Selection.param' object has no attribute 'brush'```

Comment: I used the example code from your link too, but the same thing happened. I've updated from 4.2.2 to 5.0.1. Still the same issue. Not sure why I'm getting this as it looks like it obviously worked for you

Comment: @kuatroka Make sure you update your version of `panel`, I think over 0.14.2 should work, but maybe installing the latest 1.* would be the safest option

Comment: Great, thanks. It's working now. One thing though. When I select and especially move the brush on the chart, there is a lag to translate this brush move to the table values. Is there a property to make it real-time like. Like in my first attempt?

Comment: @kuatroka You could try playing around with the `debounce` parameter like in your first example, otherwise it might help to file as an issue in the Panel github repo